# JToken does not deserialise like JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: json, f#, json.net, deserialization, nodatime

I ran into trouble deserialising a NodaTime.Instant with JToken.
When using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject the issue does not show up.

The following sample code fails with an exception:

```
let jsonOptions =
  let n = new JsonSerializerSettings()
  n.ConfigureForNodaTime(NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb)

JToken.Parse("\"2010-02-12T23:22:00Z\"")
   .ToObject<Instant>(JsonSerializer.Create(jsonOptions));
```

The stacktrace of the exception is:

```
deserialisation/deserialisation with JToken: Exception: NodaTime.Utility.InvalidNodaDataException: Unexpected token parsing Instant. Expected String, got Date.
at NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet.NodaPatternConverter`1.ReadJsonImpl(JsonReader reader, JsonSerializer serializer)
at NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet.NodaConverterBase`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject[T](JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
```

Using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize the same string works.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Instant>("\"2010-02-12T23:22:00Z\"", jsonOptions)
```

2 tests can be found here:

[Tests.fsx](https://gist.github.com/4c8156066c7c99d77998)

Any ideas on what is causing the exception?

Comment: For StackOverflow, you need to copy the offending part of the code, the expected input, and the actual output.  These should be in the question, as a minimally viable example.  The gist link can stay, but should be secondary.  Please edit the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JToken.Parse` internally use a `JSonTextReader` to parse the string.
The default behavior of the `JSonTextReader` is to parse a timedate string as in the sample to a `DateTime`.
The `NodaPatternConverter` expects a `string`, not a `DateTime`.
You could use the `JToken.Load` method instead and pass a `JSonTextReader` that has the DateParseHandling set to `DateParseHandling.None`

When you are using the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` it use the `JsonSerializerSettings` you create in `jsonOptions`.
The `ConfigureForNodaTime` method set the `DateParseHandling` property to `DateParseHandling.None` and this is why `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` works when you pass the settings that you do.

Comment: It does seem odd that there's no way of providing settings to `JToken.Parse`, as far as I can tell...

Comment: This answers my question i guess. What happens if I would need to add more serialization options than NodaTime?